# Printing LineShape in WinForms

Tags: winforms, printing

I am printing an invoice from a winforms form. All is great. *But* I want to draw boxes that will show up on the printout. I want to use lineshape from VB powerpack. However, if I could print the line outline of textboxes I would want that as well.

If I use lineshape the ControlCollection should not have it since it doesnt not descend from control. What/where is the component collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.lineshape.aspx
the invisible shapecollection does the trick thanks